# Change explorer columns in a network drive through desktop.ini

Tags: explorer, desktop.ini

I have a directory within a network drive which mainly stores MS-Office documents. I would like to alter the desktop.ini to display the title-column by default whenever someone opens this folder in his explorer.

In another directory I have a bunch of folders with additional comments to guide the users through the structure / explain the correct purpose of each folder, etc... By default the comment-column is disabled so I also need a way to enable this column by default.

Does anybody have an idea how to do this?